# Can I use a Huawei K5150 4G dongle to serve requests on a web server?

Tags: networking, dongle

In order to serve HTTP requests on an area with terrible adsl, I was considering using a 4G dongle to serve those requests, since the upload is 5x higher.

However, I'm noticing that the incoming traffic doesn't seem to reach the pc with the dongle. I tried with both a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.2) and a Windows 7 machine. On both, while Wireshark is monitoring the traffic, I can't find any incoming traffic to port 80 when I make the request from the client. Also, the client can ping the server's ip.

From what I understand, on both platforms this dongle creates an ethernet connection with ip 192.168.9.100 with the device as its gateway at 192.168.9.1; and it seems that it doesn't forward the incoming traffic (unless it's related with outgoing traffic, I presume) to the actual machine. If this is the case, what I'd need would be a way to set the pc's ip as the dongle's DMZ (or forward individual ports) but I can't find anything in its web management area.

So my question is, is it possible to achieve this goal with this device?

Comment: The dongle's public IP is normally shared with other mobile broadband users and the carrier implements NAT. This makes it difficult but not impossible to do what you want. Try searching on Google, you can find suggestions for workarounds, e.g. PageKite (https://pagekite.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the ISP (Vodafone) I was told that the behavior I was observing was caused by their network architecture, and not the dongle. Probably due to NAT, as James mentioned, though I haven't confirmed that.

I've since tried a new dongle from another carrier (NOS) and all traffic I send to its public ip address arrives successfully in the pc it's connected to, as I expected at first.

For the record, the different behavior of these carriers' network architectures might be specific the region I'm in, which is Portugal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. According to information I got Vodafone, the APN "internet.vodafone.pt" assigns a public IP to each client. The problem is the same PEN. I could first solve configuring a router in a Raspberry Pi following the instructions at these websites: https://voyager.lupomesky.cz/howto/raspi-4g-ap/ and http://www.g7smy.co.uk/?p=505. After I chose to install Multiweb ofmodemsandmen version of firmware on my TP-Link TL-WRD3500 and everything works like a charm.